# How can I still optimize the code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, optimization

I made the decision of the problem, but it does not fit in time. How else can you optimize this code (increase performance). `int` and `map` can not be touched.

Code:

```
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    map<int, int> AB;
    map<int, int>::iterator it;
    queue<int> C;
    while (1)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == -1)break;
        cin >> b;
        AB.insert(pair<int, int>(a, b));
    }
    while (1)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == -1)break;
        C.push(a);
    }
    while(!C.empty())
    {       
        it = AB.find(C.front());
        if (it == AB.end())
            cout << 0;
        else
            cout << it->second;
        cout << " ";
        C.pop();
    }
    cout << -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem which are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please explain what this code does, and not just copy-paste some `C++` code and expect a solution. Thanks

Comment: You don't need a queue

Comment: @StoryTeller Then what do I need?

Comment: @nait123321 - Process the `a` right after you verify it's not -1. Don't shove it in a queue. There's no benefit to that here.

Comment: for performance, the bottleneck of you program will always be the user! you are getting values from user with `cin>>a`. What parts of the code you need need to optimize? Assuming user will input something such 5-100 values, if your last While take more than one second (actually, some mseconds), you have a bug in your code (which I don't spot), and it will possibly never return.

Comment: @GianPaolo It's task for the Olympics. The code checks the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly improve your code by removing queue, you don't need this.
The rest of the code looks algorithmically optimal.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b;

    map<int, int> AB;
    map<int, int>::iterator it;

    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    while (1)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == -1)break;
        cin >> b;
        AB.insert(pair<int, int>(a, b));
    }

    while (1)
    {
        cin >> a;

        if (a == -1) {
            cout << -1;
            return 0;
        }

        it = AB.find(a);
        if (it == AB.end())
            cout << 0 << " ";
        else
            cout << it->second << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your example, input and output were mixed. The code checks the computer, it enters values through the space, and then reads the result.

Comment: @nait123321 Automatic system does not work with window interface like you, it works with streams (either default or file) and should work correctly with this solution. I am an ACM programmer and it always worked for me :)

Comment: Woops, but unfortunately 2 tests out of 10 still produce timed_out

Comment: Shoudn't that be `it = AB.find(a);` now that the queue C has been removed?

Comment: @PaulFloyd Thank you!

Comment: @nait123321 It is a linear algorithm now, I see no possible algorithmical improvements. However, there are possible microoptimizations like replacing `cin` and `cout` with `scanf` and `printf` or using `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`. You can try using `sync_with_stdio`, check my code out.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev,  I want to try using a `unordered_map` instead of a `map`. And also try `cin.tie(0)`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, Unfortunately, the results are the same(